# How to format and insert a character in between a string- Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I have this table.

`member_id | phone_number 
-----------+--------------
         1 | 09151234567
         2 | 09904897851
         3 | 09196332111
         4 | 09957935412
         5 | 09251279633
         6 | 09357489412
         7 | 09155974684
(7 rows)`

I format the phone_number column to this format **(63)xxxxxxxxx**. Using this code  
`update member set phone_number = regexp_replace(phone_number, '0(.)', '(63)');`

`member_id | phone_number

-----------+---------------
         1 | (63)151234567
         2 | (63)904897851
         3 | (63)196332111
         4 | (63)957935412
         5 | (63)251279633
         6 | (63)357489412
         7 | (63)155974684
(7 rows)`


And now I need to update this column again to this format **(63)xxx-xxxxxx**.
I don't want to replace a character, I need to insert a character in between the string.
I've tried using substring, regexp_replace but failed. I'm doing something wrong. I did find questions somehow related to this but they are all about string replacement.

Comment: If you have that correct format, why don't you just use `substring(phone_number from 1 for 7) || '-' || substring(phone_number from 8)` ?

Comment: I didn't used substring like that. Yours is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that in a few ways, I like this one with `right()` and `left()`:

```
update member 
set phone_number = format('%s-%s', left(phone_number, 7), right(phone_number, -7));
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert from format *(63)xxxxxxxxx* to *(63)xxx-xxxxxx*, you could try

```
UPDATE member SET phone_number = regexp_replace(phone_number, '(\(\d{2}\)\d{3})(\d{6})', '\1-\2');
```

You could also convert directly from original format to *(63)xxx-xxxxxx* by using the following

```
UPDATE member SET phone_number = regexp_replace(phone_number, '(0\d)(\d{3})(\d{6})', '(63)\2-\3');
```

I've create a sample at this link http://rextester.com/VCX4636

Answer (score 0):

You can also utilize lookbehinds.

```
select regexp_replace('(63)xxxxxxxxx','(?<=.{7})','-')
```

This is particularly useful when there is complex expression instead of `phone_number` and hence it is not desirable for readability to use it repetitively in multiple calls of `left()`, `right()` or `substring()` function.